# The user receives a truncated message (max 19109 chars) from a PHP script when calling to mysqli_real_connect

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, mysqli

I have a problem with 1 of our PHP scripts, it sometime returns truncated message.

The flow:

1. User call to search.php
2. The script process the request:

   - **a** Connect to the DB
   - **b** Build XML using the SimpleXML class
   - **c** typeCast the SimpleXML to a string.
   - **d** print that string to the client.
3. **The user receive (output to the browser) only part of the message in some cases**

after examining this issue, those are the facts I've found:

1. The maximum length is 19109 chars -> more then that, it getting truncated.
2. I logged the 2.c typeCast XML string and found out that the log contains the full XML (not truncated!).
3. other scripts that return shorter/longer response are working fine.
4. The problem is related somehow to the DB connection:

   - In order to check if the problem is related to SimpleXML or something with the XML-String, I've printed (output to the browser) a **diffrent-hardcoded-XML** on #2.d -> it got truncated as well.
   - Then I tried finding what can cause it (while the **diffrent-hardcoded-XML** is still there), so I debugged the script using "die;". Then Iv'e found out that only if mysqli_real_connect or mysql_real_connect are called, the return value  it truncated.

Any idea on how to solve/debug this issue?

Comment: So?... Is the data lost when you retrieve from MySQL or when you output to the user? I can't really follow.

Comment: congrats for this well formatted question considering it's first

Comment: Dear Alin Purcaru,
The data is lost on the output.
but it happens only when I connect to the DB in the same script.

Comment: Could this issue be browser dependent? For instance, if you trigger the call with lynx rather than Firefox do you get the entire document? I had this issue with Firefox's shoddy XML handling freaking out mid-file based on a bad UTF-8 character in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [message #2](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10212865) give you an answer? In short, PHP manual [refuses](http://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysql_real_connect&scope=quickref) that such a function barely exists in PHP.

If this is the case, you might see that truncated output because you have implicit flush enabled, so the response is flushed to the browser immidiately during script execution. Than, at some moment script calls `mysql_real_connect`, which does not exists. This cause script to stop execution, so you see partially formed output. If you have `display_errors` disabled - you will not see the error message.

So, try enabling error output in your PHP installation (`diplay_errors` config directive). Another good way to resolve this is checking, if `mysql_real_connect` really exists with [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.function-exists.php)